# Ubuntu 14.04 No Audio

Tags: 14.04, sound

As the title says, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and my sound is not working. Alsamixer shows everything is open, sound settings recognizes the card, pulseaudio shows output from chorme as well as analog output from the built in audio, and the speakers themselves have been tested on my laptop. Anyone have any guesses before I open up the tower to see if I wired something wrong?

**-edit 1-**

Forgot to include a few attempted fixes:

Already checked the results of `sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher` - it is set to no.

I have done a force reload on alsa

Attempting to delete and reinstall alsa has resulted in losing settings in general, which I managed to restore, but still no sound.

**-edit 2-**

Well, it didn't work the first time around, but updating my drivers did it for me today.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Found on http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/